# Stop a react element from rerendering once a property is set

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react component that renders a streaming page that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApBPu.png). Here are some parts of the code :

```
const [currentStream, setCurrentStream] = useState<IStream>();

const [currentStreams] = useCollectionData<IStream>(
    firestore
        .collection(firestoreCollections.livestreams)
        .limit(1)
        .where('ownerUsername', '==', location.pathname.substring(1)),
);

useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentStream(currentStreams && currentStreams[0] ? currentStreams[0] : undefined);
}, [currentStreams]);

return (
    <Box height="100%" style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <Box width="100%" style={streamBoxStyle}>
            <Box className={styles.invisibleScroll} maxWidth="100%">
                {isStreamActive && (
                    <ReactHlsPlayer
                        url={`https://stream.mux.com/${currentStream?.playbackId}.m3u8`}
                        autoplay={true}
                        controls={true}
                        style={{ position: 'relative', top: '0px' }}
                    />
                )}

                <ProfilePage currentStream={currentStream as IStream} />  <-- The profile page updates 
                                                                              the view count
            </Box>
        </Box>

        {isStreamActive && <ChatComponent streamId={currentStream?.ownerId as string} />}
    </Box>
);
```

So, everytime a new user enters the room, the currentStream's viewCount is updated which causes the whole component to rerender (which is completely normal). The problem is that when the ReactHlsPlayer rerenders, there is a split second where it is in loading state, [like in this video](https://streamable.com/804odb). So, my question is : Is there a way to make sure that, once the currentStream.playbackId is set, the ReactHlsPlayer stops rerendering everytime?

Thank you!

Comment: When the main component re-renders whenever viewCount is updated, does the currentStream?.playbackId value change that you pass to ReactHlsPlayer?

Comment: No, it doesn't! The playbackId is set once the stream is started and it doesn't change until it gets deleted when the stream ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [React.memo()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

React.Memo will check the props passed to the component and only if the props changes , it will re-render that particular component.

So if no prop changes for your `ReactHlsPlayer` it doesn't re-render and hence no abrupt loading state.

Just wrap your component with `React.memo`:

```
const ReactHlsPlayer = React.memo(function ReactHlsPlayer(props) {
  /* render using props */
});
```

Comment: It works! I tried to use the useMemo hook for this problem but it was not working since its not meant for rendering components I believe! React.memo is indeed the way to go. Thank you very much!